# get_stylesheet_directory() returns wrong URI... localhost/using vhosts

Tags: theme-development, directory

I'm trying to develop a WP theme for a client via localhost. I'm using XAMPP on Windows 8 and has set up vhosts to something like myclient.dev.
This works for stylesheet

```
<?= get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>
```

But when trying to use `get_stylesheet_directory()` (Mainly for images) I get the wrong path:
So

```
<img  class="logo" src="<?= get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>//images/logo.png">
```

The src returns:

```
http://myclient.dev/C:/Users/..../Localhost/hfclients.dev/myclient.dev/wp-content/themes/myclient.dev/images/cta-banner.jpg
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_stylesheet_directory/) and [`get_stylesheet_uri()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_stylesheet_uri/) (and probably [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/)) in your question. Please check what exactly your code has.

Comment: @Rarst, oops, yeah, fixed the question.

Comment: @devs, use `get_stylesheet_uri()` even for `<img />`'s. `get_stylesheet_directory()` is the local filepath, typically for `include` & working with files server-side.

Comment: Avoid PHP short tags like `<?=` in WordPress. That mostly doesn't work out.

Comment: @kaiser un-related and it's supported everywhere :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I was getting at in comment:

- [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_stylesheet_directory/) produces local filesystem path
- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) produces URL

Just use latter. :)

Comment: Thanks! Also thanks for not getting on me for using shorttags -_-